# Google Big Query: Need help converting Postgres query to Google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get this postgres query:

```
COALESCE(
NULLIF(drug_exposure_start_date + (INTERVAL '1 day' * days_supply), drug_exposure_start_date)
```

Into big query. Here is what I think should work:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE (
NULLIF(date_add(drug_exposure_start_date, INTERVAL (1 day * days_supply)), drug_exposure_start_date))
from `x`
```

This is the error message that I get:

> Error: Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [3:53].

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am so sorry, I thought I already marked your answer as correct. I did it now. Thank you for the help you provided me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(DATE_ADD(drug_exposure_start_date, INTERVAL days_supply DAY), drug_exposure_start_date)) 
FROM x
```

Comment: did you have chance to try?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a small modification so that the expression uses `INTERVAL <days> DAY`:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    NULLIF(date_add(drug_exposure_start_date, INTERVAL days_supply DAY),
           drug_exposure_start_date))
from x
```

You can read more about the syntax for `DATE_ADD` and other functions [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_add).